# uninstall github desktop from ubuntu

Tags: github, github-desktop

**Uninstall GitHub Desktop from Ubuntu**

How can I remove my github dektop app. It is not working perfectly, so I want to uninstall and re-install it.

Here is the command that produces an error:

```
sudo apt-get remove GitHub Desktop
```

Comment: How did you _install_ it?

Comment: using cmd from github url  debian link

Comment: Can you please include the actual command you ran while installing it on ubuntu? One of the rules on StackOverflow is to provide some code to reproduce the issue, which we can't do unless we can install it the same way you did :). As a general rule though, when you install a `.deb` file (which is I suspect how you install it), you can use `dpkg -l` to list all packages, then use `apt remove` with the package name you found using that command.

Comment: "....that produces an error" - what does that mean? Can you share that error?

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt remove github-desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways or i should say 2 commands :

```
sudo apt remove github-desktop
```

will remove the binaries, but not the configuration or data files of the package

```
sudo apt remove --purge github-desktop
```

will remove about everything regarding the package packagename, [...]
Particularly useful when you want to 'start all over' with an application because you messed up the configuration.